# Assign value to multiple pixels in an image

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to assign a single pixel value to an entire slice of an image? I have for example:

```
img = zeros(100, 200, 3, 'uint8');
```

I would like to assign the value `[200, 134, 12]` to the top half of the image. I can do

```
img(1:50, :, 1) = 200;
img(1:50, :, 2) = 134;
img(1:50, :, 3) = 12;
```

However, I would like to use broadcasting to make the assignment if possible. The following options do not work due to dimension mismatches:

```
img(1:50, :, :) = [200, 134, 12]
img(1:50, :, :) = [[200, 134, 12]]
img(1:50, :, :) = reshape([200, 134, 12], 1, 1, 3)
```

Can I apply broadcasting in this situation  in MATLAB? If so, how?

Comment: I am not sure you can do this other than how you suggest is allowed. You can always make a function if you need to use it a lot.

Comment: @AnderBiguri. Sorry about that. My firewall messes up the text boxes. Should be OK now

Comment: I guess you can `img(1:50, :, :) = repmat(reshape([200, 134, 12], 1, 1, 3),50,200)`, but I am not sure its any clearer than the 3 lines, and likely uses more processing power and memory (not that it matters at this scale)

Comment: @AnderBiguri. I would select that as an answer pretty much as written. Is the issue that broadcasting is simply not supported for assignment as it is for arithmetic?

Comment: As far as I know, the subscripted assignment must be either with a scalar or with an array of the same number of values as being indexed. [Shameless plug incoming] using [DIPimage](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib) you can do as you want: `img(1:50,:)=[200,134,12];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making my comment an answer:

I guess you can `img(1:50, :, :) = repmat(reshape([200, 134, 12], 1, 1, 3),50,200)`, but I am not sure its any clearer than the 3 lines, and likely uses more processing power and memory (not that it matters at this scale)

Answer (score 5):

The assignment operator isn't listed as one of the operators that can be used in [implicit expansion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). However you can set the top half of the image to zero and use `plus` operator for broadcasting:

```
img(1:50, :, :) = 0;
img(1:50, :, :) = img(1:50, :, :) + reshape([200, 134, 12], 1, 1, 3);
```

Comment: I think this is quite a bit more expensive than [the `repmat` solution suggested by Ander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58082448/assign-value-to-multiple-pixels-in-an-image#comment102559379_58082448).

Comment: It also may be more expensive than the method used in the question.

Comment: Yes, I think the method in the question is by far the best solution.